# I cant get my mailto contact form to work

Tags: modal-dialog, contacts, mailto, contact-form

I have tried to make a contact form in a modal window. I thought I had done everything correctly but when I click send, I don't receive the email. Can anybody please show me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks very much in advance. Merry Xmas!

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Contact McGregor Beauty</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="contact" method="post" action="mailto:aka_pipsqueak@msn.com">
Your Name   &nbsp;<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Please write your name here" required>
<br />
Your Email   &nbsp;<input class="input-xlarge" type="email" placeholder="Please enter your email address here" required><br />
Phone(Optional)  &nbsp;<input class="input-large" type="number" placeholder="Add a telephone number"><hr />
<label><strong>Treatments of Interest</strong></label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Waxing & Tinting">Waxing & Tinting
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Massage">Massage
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Reflexology">Reflexology
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="Manicure/Pedicure">Manicure & Pedicure
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="MLD">MLD
</label>
<br />
<label><strong>Your Questions/Comments</strong></label>
<textarea rows="2" style="width:500px" type="text" required></textarea>

<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: In a trimmed down version, this works for me, in the sense that my mail client popups a email window where I can finish and send the mail...

Comment: Do you have a default mail client configured on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

what mail server are you using?

where is the server side code used to handle the http request of the form?

Just having a form in html isn't going to do anything, and an action of mailto: is not correct, nor would you want to do this because this email address can be seen in the markup and will be spammed until you close it.

what programming language are you planning to use?

Here's a basic example you can follow using php:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp